# Retrieve the name of olImportance and not the number in Outlook vbs

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I need to send an email notification every time which user change any field from outlook task.

My problem is that the Status and Importance related with numbers.
For example in Item.Importance 1=Low.
So when i send the email notification i have Status:1 instead of Low.
It is possible to get the String and not the number of the field.
Find my code which send the email

```
 With oMsg
   .Recipients.Add(owner)
   .Recipients.ResolveAll
   .Subject = "Task Status Changes Report"
   .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY> Task "  & "<strong>" & Item.Subject & "</strong>" & "   which assign to " & "<strong>"& assigned  & "</strong>" & "<br/>" _
           & "<strong>" & "Priority: " & "</strong>" &  "<strong>" & "Low" & "</strong>"  & "<br/>" & _ 
             "<strong>" & "Priority: " & "</strong>" &  "<strong>" & Item.Importance & "</strong>"  & "<br/>" &
"</BODY></HTML>"
 .Send
```

End With

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array containing the strings, use the olImportance field to index into the array. Outlook doesn't store the texts, because they differ in foreign language implementations. From a programmers point of view, it's much easier to have the numbers than having to deal with french, german, vietnamese and arabian words in addition to the english ones.

Comment: Hello, Because i'm beginner in vbs i'm confuse how can create an array with the strings and every time that a user do a change in Status to send an email that the Status change to Normal for example.

Comment: Nevermind, Thank you very much for your help i found the way to do it and it works